# How can I compute the hessian of the loss function in MXNet?

Tags: python, neural-network, gradient, data-science, mxnet

I'm learning MXNet at the moment and I'm working on a problem using neural nets. I'm interested in observing the curvature of my loss function with respect to the network weights but as best I can tell higher order gradients are not supported for neural network functions at the moment. Is there any (possibly hacky) way that I could still do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the discussion [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/10002)

The gist of it is that not all operators support higher order gradients at the moment.

In Gluon you can try the following:

```
with mx.autograd.record():
  output = net(x)
  loss = loss_func(output)
  dz = mx.autograd.grad(loss, [z], create_graph=True)  # where [z] is the parameter(s) you want

dz[0].backward()  # now the actual parameters should have second order gradients
```

Taken from this [forum thread](https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/obtaining-second-order-derivatives-for-a-function-wrt-arbitrary-parameters-in-the-computation-graph/1223)